# Turning slider numbers into abbreviations with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My slider code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 1000000,
    step: 25000,
    range: true,
    values: [0, 1000000],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      for (var i = 0; i < ui.values.length; ++i) {
        console.log(ui.values[i].split("").length); // ERROR HERE
        $("span.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").text(ui.values[i]);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

However, I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: ui.values[i].split is not a function
```

For now, I want to get the length of the string.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to get the 'length' property out of a number instead of a string.
You should first convert it to string and then get the length like:

```
ui.values[i].toString().length
```